# Not updating the annotation title and subtitle in mkMapView in iphone at appropriate time

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mkmapview, latitude-longitude

I am showing my current location on mapView.It shows the blue dot.I want to add annotation on that blue so that it shows the latitude and longitude in title and subtitle of annotation but it shows null in both field for sometimes and after few minutes it shows the lat/long in title and subtitle.I want to show that lat/long with the load of view.Please help me regarding this to show the lat/long on annotation as quick as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i startUpdatingLocation my locationManager in loadView rather than viewDidLoad and it works fine for me...